# How do I troubleshoot a CakePHP application stuck in a redirect loop?

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

I've got a CakePHP site that is stuck in a redirect loop.  I've removed every piece of code that does a redirect & I've turned off autoRedirect on the Auth object.

This occurred when I logged out of the site and has persisted even after deleting all cookies and just trying to load the homepage. The index action is in `$this->Auth->allow`.

I should not, it keeps trying to redirect me to /users/login which then redirect loops. The login action is also in the allowed list

Does anyone have any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Could this be NeutrinoCMS perhaps?

Comment: Do you have any custom code in your users/login function that would redirect? Is there something in your controllers before<Filter, Render, etc.> that might cause a redirect?

Comment: Nope not running any CMS

Comment: Um..since we don't know anything about your code, and you say you've removed all the redirects, did you check your .htaccess files? Did you check the response with FireBug? Apache logs?

Comment: `parent::beforeFilter();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `<cake>/app/app_controller` should have a `beforeFilter()` method with all behaviors of **Auth** component. One of those behaviors is where to send when a user is not logged in.

you will be looking for something like:

```
// If cake should redirect automatically or you will do it in the User.login()
$this->Auth->autoRedirect = true; 
// And if the autoRedirect is true, where to redirect
$this->Auth->loginRedirect = '/user/login';
```

G'luck

Answer (score 7):

This also occurs in CakePHP 1.3 if you add a custom component that extends **Component** instead of **Object**.

Comment: thank you so so much, I would vote 1000 up if I could , I was stuck on this thing a couple of hour, God bless you :)

Answer (score 3):

hey sometimes, if you db connection are wrong,,, the application will be trying connect to the mysql, and will be in looping.
So, look allways if the database config are right.

good bye.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem exactly, and when I restarted the mySql service the redirect stopped. So add this to your list of things to check.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears that there are a number of reasons why this could happen in my case i was trying to access

cakeapplication/users/add

and it came out that i was missing

```
'add'=>'*',
```

in the permissions array in usersController.php

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem and I know not why but it was fixed when I changed (in my AppController beforeFilter() method):

```
$this->Auth->allow('*');
```

to

```
$this->Auth->allow();
```

Of course then in my subsequent controllers I deny the approriate actions.